# pandas reference NaN value with multiple keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, the [Trade] column in first dataframe has 3 NaN values,
I need to fill them with a referenc dataframe, which you might see below this the first df.
You can use various methods to populate NaN value. Join, merge, concat, replace, whatever that works easily.
thank you

```
    Trade        ID     Toy_company
0   D255/FE     192     Duplo
1   L217/SN     255     Duplo
2   NaN         195     Lego
3   NaN         256     Duplo
4   D255/FE     192     Duplo
5   D255/FE     192     Duplo
6   D250/AT     192     Duplo
7   D250/AT     192     Duplo
8   L195/AE     195     Lego
9   NaN         195     Lego
10  L256/PE     256     Lego
```

reference dataframe:

```
   Trade_ID     Item    Company
0   D255/FE     192     Duplo
1   D217/SN     255     Duplo
2   L12A/BA     195     Lego
3   L999/CC     256     Lego
```

Requirement:
1. Only fill NaN value according to the info in reference dataframe, on TWO keys: Item+Company. Leave it NaN if can't be referenced.
2. Do not correct any exsiting info, only impact on NaN values

So the final result should be:

```
        Trade        ID     Toy_company
    0   D255/FE     192     Duplo
    1   L217/SN     255     Duplo
    2   L12A/BA     195     Lego
    3   NaN         256     Duplo
    4   D255/FE     192     Duplo
    5   D255/FE     192     Duplo
    6   D250/AT     192     Duplo
    7   D250/AT     192     Duplo
    8   L195/AE     195     Lego
    9   L12A/BA     195     Lego
    10  L256/PE     256     Lego
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `merge()` method:

```
In [347]: d1['Trade'] = (d1['Trade'].fillna(
                             d1.merge(d2.rename(columns={'Item':'ID','Company':'Toy_company'}),
                                      how='left')['Trade_ID']))

In [348]: d1
Out[348]:
      Trade   ID Toy_company
0   D255/FE  192       Duplo
1   L217/SN  255       Duplo
2   L12A/BA  195        Lego
3       NaN  256       Duplo
4   D255/FE  192       Duplo
5   D255/FE  192       Duplo
6   D250/AT  192       Duplo
7   D250/AT  192       Duplo
8   L195/AE  195        Lego
9   L12A/BA  195        Lego
10  L256/PE  256        Lego
```